# If the coordinates of the vertices $B$ and $D$ are $(7,3)$ and $(2,6)$ respectively, find the coordinates of the vertices $A$ and $C$.

Tags: geometry

The sides of the rectangle $ABCD$ are parallel to the co-ordinate axes. If the coordinates of the vertices $B$ and $D$ are $(7,3)$ and $(2,6)$ respectively, find the coordinates of the vertices  $A$ and $C$.

Comment: I do not believe this is a question to be asked here.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you drawn a sketch of the problem?  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you explain what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

They tell you $B$ and $D$, and they tell you that it is a rectangle parallel to the coordinate axes. So I would start by plotting $B$ and $D$ and drawing a rectangle using those vertices. Since $C$ has to touch $D$ with a straight line, the $x$ coordinates must match, which is $2$. Since $C$ has to touch $B$ with straight line, the $y$ coordinate must match which is $3$. So $C$ has to be $(2,3)$. Use similar reasoning to find $A$.